# run a for loop in a bash script using multiple cores

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have to call a program several times iterating a parameter.
I would like to know if it is possible to run the for loop using multiple cores...

```
for ((par=4; par<=10 ; par++))
 do

   ./executeprog par

done
```

my attempt (using 7 cores):

```
seq 4 10 | parallel -j 7 --workdir $PWD ./executeprog {}
```